# Background Image not displayed in html

Tags: html, css

```
<body>
<div>
    <div class="page1">
    </div> 
</body>
.page1{
background-image:url(../images/1.jpg);
background-size:cover;
background-position:center; 
width:100%;
height:100%;
display:block;
position:relative;
 }
```

This is my code for setting a background image for a webpage, but unfortunately it's not displayed. Can someone help me correct this code?

Comment: for one you have an extra `div` in there that isn't being closed (that's not the reason though). you don't need `display: block;` because `div`s are block by default. Everything else looks good so I would say there is a problem with the path of your image, double check that it's in that directory.

Comment: When I set height as '100px',image gets displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I understand now, you need to do

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Background is not showing because your div needs content. 
2 options:
You can set the background for body instead.

```
body{
    background-image:url(../images/1.jpg);
}
```

Or set the height of the div to the height of the image

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to put a closing `</div>`

```
<div>
    <div class="page1"></div>
    </div>
```

The problem now is tha your  `<div class="page1"></div>` is emptry. You need to put some elements inside so that the image can be displayed.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WFvhx/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you html document is not well formed.

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<-- style block have to be contained within a <style> tag -->
<style>
    .page1{
        background-image:url(../images/1.jpg);
        background-size:cover;
        background-position:center; 
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        display:block;
        position:relative;
     }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div class="page1">
    </div>
</div> <-- this tag was missing in your question -->
</body>
```

Second possibility, your image is not properly linked. The way it is written, it is in a folder 'images' parrallel to the one you html document is hold. So, find what relativity there is between your document and the image and try modifying it's source *url(../images/1.jpg);* .

Answer (score 0):

When defining the path to another object, I find it easier to define the file path using ~/f1/f2/file rather than trying to work from the current directory using ../f1/f2/file. What the ~ indicates is to start at the top level directory and work its way down the file structure. Much easier.